# Settings field is not showing up in the general options page

Tags: settings-api

I've tried to add a pretty basic test case based on a tutorial by creating a custom settings field in the general options page in the admin area. Problem is the settings field is not showing up, nor any error, just nothing. So no idea how to track down the cause of the no show. :/

```
function initialize_my_theme_options() {
    //define the settings field
    add_settings_field(
        'my_message',               //The ID
        'My Greeting Message',         // the label for field
        'my_message_display',  //The callback function
        'general'                       //the page
    );

    //register the footer_message setting the general section
    register_setting(
        'general',
        'my_message'
    );
}
add_action('admin_init','initialize_my_theme_options');


function my_message_display() {
    echo '<input type="text" name="my_message" id="my_message" value="" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and it is working fine. I hope you are checking the field on the right place. It should be and it is under Settings > General in your WordPress admin

[image]

Just used the given code

Comment: Thanks for testing... Makes things even more odd. :/ and yes i've looked on the correct options page. which wp version are you using? 4.1?

Comment: Yes, I tested this on 4.1

Comment: Strange... i've tested it on 4.1 too... No idea why it is working in your setup and mine is failing :/

Comment: Have you tried this in a fresh installation?

Comment: Yep. Complete fresh install out of the box.

Comment: Even more strange. On another, already existing, worked on, install, it works when i paste the lines in. But on the complete unaltered fresh install it doesn't.

Comment: Argh, i've found the reason of the not showing content. The theme were i've entered the code in the functions.php wasn't activated. Even though i've clicked to activate it right after the creation. Awkward mistake never the less. :/